# Run a vim macro from inside a bash script

Tags: bash, vim

In a bash script I want to edit a file. Is there a way to write a macro in vim, save it and then call it in bash script?

Answer (score 9):

No problem:
Create the macro file with vi commands. For example:

```
:1,$s/a/b/g
:wq
```

Then run `vi -s macro_file data_file`

One advice: Try to use `sed`/`awk` and instead of `vi` for this purpose

Comment: And there is the equivalent but more obscure `+` syntax as in: `vim +PluginInstall +qall` for [installing Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim).

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the use of vim to create HTML versions of files with vim :

```
for f in *.c; do
    vim -f +"syn on" +"run! syntax/2html.vim" +"wq" +"q" "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ex`, which comes with vim and is the command line tool for vim.

Eran's answer is definitely correct, but I'd personally use `ex -c` (`vim -c` is also possible):

```
> echo asdf > blub
> ex blub -c "normal a_" -c "normal l.l.l." -c wq
> cat blub
a_s_d_f_
```

This is my preferred way, because there are not multiple files.

If you remap escape to jj (for example), you can easily make more complicated normal statements:

```
ex file -c "normal a_jjl.l.l." -c wq
```

For your information:

- **normal** sends letters in normal mode to
- **wq** quits the program
- to send multiple commands in one string (no additional -c option), use the pipe character |. But: This does not work in the case of normal.
- This works only for 10 -c's. But for more commands, I would recommend to create a file.